# multisite (MU) Subdomain- only one wordpress install

Tags: multisite

I have wordpress v5.3.2 installed on my site. I want to make it a MultiSite and I have read and done all steps mentioned in Wordpress documentation. 
I like to set my network as SubDomains. I have Direct Admin panel and I don't know if there is anything else I must do on my host.

Everything seems fine since my Network setup is completed and I am able to create sites on my network. The problem is that I can not access either the subdomain address or its dashboard. I get an Internal Server Error when trying to go to dashboard.

I wonder why it doesn't work or recognize the wordpress installation on any of my sub-domains. Here's what is written about MU on Wordpress site:

"Multisite is a WordPress feature which allows users to create a network of sites on a **single WordPress installation**"
https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/multisite/

I'd appreciate your help because I am stuck with it for days.

My main site:  http://zagraco.ir/

Subdomain: elixir.zagraco.ir

** Also, I need to create 10 subdomains. Is there any limitations for subdomains?

Comment: Have you actually created the subdomains? You don't just create them in WordPress; you also have to create the subdomains one by one with your registrar or host.

Comment: Yes.Actually, I did. I have done it for kaveh.zagraco.ir subdomain. It creates a folder in public_html. So, what should I do now to use the wordpress and Theme that I have on my main site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with some help from Direct Admin Support. Here's how I did it:

When using WordPress multisite and creating extra sites in WordPress which are sub domains, then you shouldn't create the subdomains as regular subdomains. 
In DirectAdmin under the domain for which you have installed WordPress multisite, you should create a **domain pointer** as a "**alias**" pointer.

It is in the section of Advanced features and you can add your domain pointers. Make sure you check the "alias" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not a WordPress problem, but a server setup problem.

WordPress is perfectly capable of handling the requests to the subdomains, but those requests never reach WordPress. Your server is not configured to map those subdomains on to your WordPress install. That's why you get the placeholder, as that's what your server is setup to present when it's asked to serve a domain it doesn't know how to handle

To fix this will require adjustments to the Nginx configs, or Apache vhosts, so you will need to contact your hosting provider, or make the relevant changes yourself

Comment: Thank you. Can you be more specific about the configs on server? Any documentation available?

Comment: Unfortunately no, that's beyond the scope of this stack. I have no idea what your configs look like, how they're setup, or where they're located, I don't even know if it's Nginx or Apache. The modifications to them require expertise and knowledge in that software, not WordPress. Ask your host, or if you've set it up yourself look up how to map subdomains to a folder for your server software, maybe even ask on server fault